Google Maps: Over 200 markers and clustering - Slow
I get the data async from the backend so there is not really a way to load it from memory.
I created the map like this
@Composable
private fun HoaxLocatorScreen(
    cameraPosition: CameraPositionState,
    userMarkerState: MarkerState,
    userMarkerKey: PersistentList<HoaxLocationPoint>,
    hoaxLocation: HoaxLocation,
    hoaxVenues: ImmutableList<HoaxVenueCluster>,
    onClusterTap: () -> Unit,
) {
    GoogleMap(
        cameraPositionState = cameraPosition,
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxSize()
    ) {
        when (hoaxLocation) {
            HoaxLocation.HoaxFineLocation -> {
                MarkerComposable(
                    userMarkerKey,
                    state = userMarkerState
                ) {
                    HoaxUserFineLocationIndicator()
                }
            }

            is HoaxLocation.HoaxCoarseLocation -> {
                hoaxLocation.radius?.toDouble()?.let { locationRadius ->
                    Circle(
                        center = userMarkerState.position,
                        radius = locationRadius,
                        fillColor = HoaxYellow.copy(alpha = 0.3f),
                        strokeColor = HoaxYellow,
                        strokeWidth = 2f
                    )
                }
            }

            HoaxLocation.HoaxUnknownLocation -> {
            }
        }

        HoaxClustering(
            hoaxVenues = hoaxVenues,
        )
    }
}

and
@Composable
fun HoaxClustering(
    hoaxVenues: ImmutableList<HoaxVenueCluster>,
) {
    val clusterManager = rememberClusterManager<HoaxVenueCluster>()

    clusterManager?.algorithm =
        PreCachingAlgorithmDecorator(NonHierarchicalDistanceBasedAlgorithm())

    val renderer = rememberClusterRenderer(
        clusterContent = { hoaxVenueCluster ->
            HoaxClusterItem(
                size = hoaxVenueCluster.size
            )
        },
        clusterItemContent = { hoaxVenue ->
            HoaxVenueMarker()
        },
        clusterManager = clusterManager,
    )


    SideEffect {
        clusterManager ?: return@SideEffect
        clusterManager.setOnClusterClickListener {
            false
        }
        clusterManager.setOnClusterItemClickListener {
            false
        }
        clusterManager.setOnClusterItemInfoWindowClickListener {

        }
    }

    SideEffect {
        if (clusterManager?.renderer != renderer) {
            clusterManager?.renderer = renderer ?: return@SideEffect
        }
    }

    if (clusterManager != null) {
        Clustering(
            items = hoaxVenues,
            clusterManager = clusterManager,
        )
    }

}

But it becomes so slow.
Yes, I checked and I do not do crazy amount of recomposition.
I tried using that algorithm which only shows markers that are visible on the screen but that combined with clustering makes a bad choice (cluster marker count becomes dynamic and changes based on the view position)
Is there something I can do?

Why do you set listeners in SideEffect? SideEffect is invoked after every sucecssful recomposition

Just a suggestion @No_name . Is there a specific need to make view position as dynamic? I implemented clustering years back but at that time there was no concept of recomposition. All it was doing when we were scrolling on the map,  based on its location there was a API call made and retrieval was happening in a matter of secs.

I am building a user tracking application so showing the user's real time location is important
